# Pointer to a variable that (should) no more exists

Tags: c

I would like to discuss the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    int i;
    int * ptr ;

    for ( i = 0; i < 3; ++i ){
        int tmp = 1;
        ptr = &tmp;
    }

    printf ("%d\n", *ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

As far as I know, a new variable *tmp* is created and then destroyed every time the for cycle is executed. As a consequence, at the end the pointer *ptr* could no more refer *a priori* to a memory area which contain the integer value 1 (since it may happen that it had been erased, or overwritten by new data).
On the other hand, I executed that code many times on many systems, and it always worked.
Question: is it basically a coincidence due to the operating system / compiler in use? Is it generally *wrong* to expect *ptr to be 1, right?

My apologies for the easy question, but I am sure an answer will allow me to better understand why a more complex code I have written does not work and produce a segmentation fault error (compared to the code in this post, it is the same of relying on having the pointer *ptr* always "well-defined").

Comment: It's undefined behavior  Using a pointer to a variable that is out of scope is incorrect.

Comment: You cannot conclude the correctness of a C program from just running it. You need to check the source code and verify that it follows the language rules.

Comment: From he C11 Standard (draft):

"*6.2.4/2  [...] If an object is referred to outside of its
lifetime, the behavior is undefined. The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when
the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.*"

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First : Your understanding is correct

2nd: Try using the code in release version with compiler optimisations flag on. In all probability you'll get a core dump

Its also possible that since your code is very small, the run time memory you access is actually belongs to your executable. This piece of code in a big program / in a library should crash immediately.